# all commands not found on zsh

Tags: terminal, command

I am getting errors i.e. 'command not found' after using 'cd' or 'ls' or 'clear' [click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKXSd.png)

I have tried the below suggestions to set the path but after setting the path by using the below command:
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH

[Add to the PATH on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion and up](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)

after this, it works properly but when I restart the terminal it again throw the error "command not found"

zsh: command not found: clear

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely messed up your system paths. run `chsh`

Enter password:
Then you will see a file open

Run the commands:

`/Shell`

`$`

`i`

delete bash
and type in zsh

`:wq`

You might need to restart for the changes to take effect.